# How many times element of one array occurs in another array?( HackerRank sparse arrays problem)

Tags: c++, beginner, array, set

with basic knowledge of multiset and vectors in c++ I solved the following problem.
How can I improve my code and also handle any input errors?

Problem statement:

> There is a collection of input strings and a collection of query strings. For each query string, print how many times it occurs in the list of input strings.
> Input Format
> The first line contains an integer n, the input strings
> Each of the next n lines contains a string .
> The next line contains q, the size of . query strings
> Each of the q next lines contains a string .

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<set>
#include<string>


int main()
{
    std::multiset<std::string> strings;
    std::vector<std::string> queries;
    size_t n,q;//size of the set, no of queries
    if (std::cin >> n){}
    else 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    
    std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::string input;
        getline(std::cin, input);
        strings.insert(input);
    }
    
    if (std::cin >> q) {}
    else 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        std::string input;
        getline(std::cin, input);
        queries.push_back(input);
    }

    //calling the function
    for (auto temp : queries)
    {
        if (strings.find(temp) != strings.end())//if the element exist int the set
            std::cout << strings.count(temp) << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "0" << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advice I can give you is to use a `std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> counter_map`. Then, you iterate over the input strings (call each string `input_string`, for example) and do `counter_map[input_string]++;`.

Further on, when your query strings are read from the console, do something like

```
for (const auto& query_string : queries) {
    std::cout << counter_map[query_string] << "\n";
}
```

In some sense, you could say that the solution I am providing runs in \$\Theta(q + n)\$, whereas your solution runs in \$\Theta(qn)\$. ("In some sense" since I am not taking into account the number of characters in each query/input string.)